# Oracle AVG COUNT

Tags: oracle, count, average

I have this query:

```
SELECT TRUNC(date_added,'MM'), count(*)
FROM payments_log l, product p
WHERE l.amount > 0
  AND l.product_id = p.product_id
  AND p.subproduct_id = 238
  AND TRUNC(l.date_added) BETWEEN TO_DATE('01012020','MMDDYYYY') AND TO_DATE('01012021','MMDDYYYY')
  AND l.return_code = 1
GROUP BY TRUNC(date_added,'MM')
ORDER BY TRUNC(date_added,'MM');
```

In addition to the count, per month, I want a column that is the average each month, of the total......not sure how to do this in the same query.

Comment: Do you mean each month's count expressed as a percentage of the overall count? `COUNT(*) * 1.0 / COUNT(*) OVER ()`?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.  So, I'd have:  MONTH, MONTH_COUNT, AVG OF SUM OF ALL MONTHS.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: the DDL (`CREATE TABLE`) statements for your tables; the DML (`INSERT`) statements for some sample data that replicates your problem; your expected output; and an explanation of the expected output. Your use of average is slightly confusing as you are not describing what you are averaging very well and a worked example with input data and expected output would help to clarify the issue.

Comment: What do you mean by "average of sum of all months"? "Sum of all months" is a single number, so what's its average? If you can't express your question more clearly, at least include a very simple example. If you had three months, with the counts 30, 50, 20 (in the `count` column, in the three rows for those three months), what should be shown in each row in this new column? Just tell us the numbers - no need to try to explain them, since that seems difficult.

Answer (score 1):

To get:

> I want a column that is the average each month, of the total

You appear to want to use the `AVG` analytic function over the entire range:

```sql
SELECT month,
       cnt,
       AVG( cnt ) OVER () AS avg_cnt
FROM   (
  SELECT TRUNC(date_added,'MM') AS month,
         COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM   payments_log l
         INNER JOIN product p
         ON ( l.product_id = p.product_id )
  WHERE  l.amount > 0
  AND    p.subproduct_id = 238
  AND    l.date_added >= DATE '2020-01-01'
  AND    l.date_added <  DATE '2021-01-01'
  AND    l.return_code = 1
  GROUP BY TRUNC(date_added,'MM')
)
ORDER BY month
```

You also should use ANSI joins rather than the (confusing) legacy comma joins and can filter on the `date_added` column without needing the `TRUNC` function (which, if you do use it, would prevent Oracle from using an index on the `date_added` column and would require a function-based index on `TRUNC( date_added )`).

*(Note: `BETWEEN` is inclusive so that you will include `2021-01-01` in your range rather than just those dates in 2020; I am assuming that you do not want this date but if you do then you can set the upper bound to `l.date_added <  DATE '2021-01-02'`.)*

---

If you want the number of counts per month as a fraction of the total number of counts (this is not an average) then, again, you want to use an analytic function:

```sql
SELECT month,
       cnt,
       cnt / SUM( cnt ) OVER () AS fraction_of_total_cnt
FROM   (
  SELECT TRUNC(date_added,'MM') AS month,
         COUNT(*) AS cnt
  FROM   payments_log l
         INNER JOIN product p
         ON ( l.product_id = p.product_id )
  WHERE  l.amount > 0
  AND    p.subproduct_id = 238
  AND    l.date_added >= DATE '2020-01-01'
  AND    l.date_added <  DATE '2021-01-01'
  AND    l.return_code = 1
  GROUP BY TRUNC(date_added,'MM')
)
ORDER BY month
```

Comment: Hi.  Only thing wrong I think is that the AVG_CNT is the same for all months.  It should be different.   Since there is a different total for each month, then the count for each month / total should be different.   I think this is different than AVG???

Comment: @LandonStatis Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67011281/edit) your question with details of the input to your query, what you expect the output to be for that input and how you expect the average to be calculated. We can't understand why you think the average should be different for every month if you don't tell us how you expect the average to be calculated. Which rows/columns are being averaged and over what ranges?

Comment: @LandonStatis "the count for each month / total should be different" Which total? You do not calculate a total anywhere in your query.

Comment: @MT0 - you say (to the OP) that "[you] appear to want to use the `AVG` analytic function". I read that, so I re-read the OP's question two more times, and I have no idea why you think the OP "appears to want" to use that, or anything else. Just because he said "AVG COUNT" in the title? Obviously the guy is not using the terms in their technical meaning.

Comment: @mathguy The OP said in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67011281/oracle-avg-count/67012769?noredirect=1#comment118450674_67011281) "AVG OF SUM OF ALL MONTHS" and I have to assume that they know what an average is. Subsequent to that it appears that they do not mean the arithmetic mean, geometric mean, median or mode and that their use of the term "average" is probably misplaced .... but initially I had to give them the benefit of the doubt that what they asked for was actually what they wanted; now that we know it probably is not an "average" we can ask for a clarification.